# How to pass Javascript variables in MySQL query

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js

I've done some research and I'm getting conflicting answers, so here it goes. Do you have to pass JS variables into PHP first or can you insert them directly into a MySQL table? I have this running in node.js, thanks!

```
var part = [];
var des = [];
var price = [];
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "parts"
});

request('URL', function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        getPartNumber();
        getDescription();
        getPrice();
        con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        for (var i = 0; i<part.length; i++){
            var sql = "INSERT INTO data_9_17 (partNumber, description, price) VALUES (part[i], des[i], price[i])";
            con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("1 record inserted, ID: " + result.insertId);
            });
        }
});

function getPartNumber() {
$("input[name = 'sku']").each(function() { part.push($(this).val()) });
}

function getDescription() {
$(".ellipsis_text").each(function() { des.push($(this).text()) });
}

function getPrice() {
$(".sellprice, .dbl").each(function() { price.push($(this).text()) });
}
}
});
```

Comment: If you are on Node, you can do it directly.

Comment: But not that way...remember that with node you have server side javascript...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your query string should go like this:

`"INSERT INTO data_9_17 (partNumber, description, price) VALUES ('" + part[i] + "', '" + des[i] + "', '" + price[i] + "')";`

You can concenate values by using `+`. Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_oper_concatenate) out.

Edit: I made a mistake. Didn't put `'` in. Fixed now...
Anyways, J Johnson is right. It's better to use Prepared Statements because of SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use prepared statement, like this:

```
var query = 'INSERT INTO data_9_17 (partNumber, description, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';

con.query(query, [part[i], des[i], price[i]], function(err, results) ... )

// You will put your variables inside []
```

If you want more information, refer to the `mysql` npm module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values

Comment: I only intend to run this on my desktop, but I totally get what you are saying. Thanks, J Johnson!

Comment: No problem @GarrettPenfield :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate your query string with the values of the variables:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO data_9_17 (partNumber, description, price) VALUES (" + part[i] + ", " + des[i] + ", " + price[i] + ")";
```

For security reasons, I recommend you to use the prepared statement:

```
var sql = mysql.format("INSERT INTO data_9_17 (partNumber, description, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (part[i], des[i], price[i]));

con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
.....
.....
.....
}
```